# Change Oxyplot Axisline color

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, oxyplot

I create a new `Plot` and its `PlotModel` with a black `BackgroundColor`
Then I create a new `Axes`. The X-Axis doesn't matter, it's invisible.
The Y-Axis is:

```
var valueAxisY = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, minValue, maxValue)
{
   AxislineThickness = 2,
   AxislineColor = OxyColors.White,
   MinorGridLinethickness = 2,
   MajorGridLineThickness = 2,
   MinorTickSize = 4,
   MajorTickSize = 7,
   TicklineColor = OxyColors.White,
   FontSize = 40,
   TextColor = OxyColors.White
}
```

Everything works BUT the Y-Axisline. It seems to stay black no matter what. The ticks starting 1-2 pixels on the left of where the line should be are white and have the correct length.

Is this the wrong parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was `Undefined`.

```
var valueAxisY = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis(AxisPosition.Left, minValue, maxValue)
{
   LineStyle = LineStyle.Undefined
};
```

Somehow this is a visible, editable, continuous line.

Answer (score 0):

If you define the axis line you should also hide the border arround plot area, because it is drawn over the axis line.

```
using model.PlotAreaBorderThickness = 0
```